# How to set the WordPress Feature image for post be the same size regardless of the size of the original picture?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to set the feature image for my WordPress site. However even though all the images have the same width. Their height varies, causing the 3 article grid to have the 3 articles below it to not be straight as the height of the first 3 articles varies. Is there anything I could write on functions.php that could help with this? Thanks so much.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, please include the code you use to display the featured images. Depending on the functions used, you can choose a size to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use featured (thumbnail) images as background-image. for instance,

```
<style>
.post-thumbnail-img {
background-size:cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
height: 300px;
width:100%;}
</style>

<div class="post-thumbnail-img" style="background-image: url('<? echo the_post_thumbnail_url();?>')">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set Thumbnail images using WordPress `CROP` function .

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150 );
```

Comment: Thanks! Do I just add this to the functions.php?

Comment: I added this to the functions.php but the feature images have not changed at all.

Comment: You should use Regenerate Thumbnails plugin to regenerate all uploaded image to new thumbnail size.